# Destroy variable(s) in NASM x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, bare-metal

I need to redefine/remove a variable in assembly, so it can be redefined
I'm working on bare metal so I can't use windows/linux OS calls.

My Code:

```
; Print String code
; Invoke with CALL PRINTS, otherwise it jump to a random command
prints:
    mov ax, 0x07c0
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, msg
    cld
    jmp .loop
.loop:lodsb
    or al, al ; zero=end or str
    jz .done  ; get out
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0
    int 0x10
    jmp .loop
.done:
    popa
    pop msg
    ret
 
msg   db 'AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH', 0
```

Comment: You can't "destroy" a static variable.  But if you want, you can overwrite that space with some other data.

Comment: `pop msg` isn't even encodeable; the destination can't be an immediate.  `pop [msg]` would be possible but not useful (copying from the stack to the first 2 bytes of the `db`.  Of course, the stack is also messed up from running `popa` without anything at the start of the function to push stuff on the stack first.  But that appears to be a separate bug from the thing you're asking about.  Just use stack space if you need uninitialized scratch space you can free when you're done.

Comment: If you mean the name `msg` conflicts with other things you want to call `msg`, then tough; make up unique names.  (Or use `.msg:` to get a full name like `prints.msg`.)

Comment: @NateEldredge do you mean like `mov [msg], 0`?

Comment: @PeterCordes no, I want to redefine it, it is a print string command and I need a way for it to be invoked multiple times (by programs, drivers, kernel, ETC.)

Comment: If you want your print function to be reusable, pass it a pointer arg instead of having it print a static buffer.  Your `msg: db ...` is exactly like `static char msg[] = "...";` in C.  If that's not what you want, don't do that.

Comment: That ^^^. If you are looking to change `msg`, put it in `.data` section. That way value could be overwritten. Eg `.text \ prints: \ mov ax, 0x07c0 \ ...` `.data \ msg db 'ah'`

Comment: Endless screaming, huh?  I'm probably missing something, but you do know line 9 is just jmp to line 10?
It probably makes sense to rotate the loop and conditional-branch at the bottom.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there is a (good) way to do it, so I'll just let them choose the VAR name to print, and if it's conflicting, I'll just let NASM screem at them.

Comment: You don't need a separate print function for every separate string.  Write one function that takes a pointer arg, instead of making this a macro or something.  Or is that what you mean by "let them choose"?  The mechanism for doing that is kind of the key point.  If your function just takes a pointer (e.g. in DS:SI), then your function doesn't have to worry about symbol names at all, so IDK why you even mention it.